# Links rendered outside of a router context cannot handle clicks

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error:

> Links rendered outside of a router context cannot handle clicks

### on a `<Link>` Tag and can't figure out the cause for it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router , Route, Link , hashHistory } from 'react-router';


class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
       <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
             <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <Content/>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    );
  }}


class Content extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
           <section  id="content-wrapper" className="container">
                <div className="row-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                     <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                          <Link to="/survey"><img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/survey.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" /></Link>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                         <Link to="/media"> <img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/media.png" alt="Generic placeholder image"/></Link>


                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                          <Link to="/paticipants"><img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/part.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" /></Link>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                     <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                          <Link to="/themes"><img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/themes.png" alt="Generic placeholder image"/></Link>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                          <Link to="/tools"><img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/tools.png" alt="Generic placeholder image"/></Link>


                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                          <Link to="/questionaire"><img className="img-circle" src="assets/images/quest.png" alt="Generic placeholder image"  /></Link>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </section>
        );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this, im very new to react!

Comment: Well, can you post more information about your problem? It seems that your `<Link>` is being placed in the wrong place. If you can show us more details about your code, it would be easier to help you! :)

Comment: @WilliamMartins i have editted the quesstion with my code for reference.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Did my answer help you with that?

Answer (score 9):

You're not really using React Router correctly, you need to render a `<Router>` component and, inside of `<Router>`, render your routes (`<Route>` component).

You will need something like that:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="my-path" component={MyPath} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

Since you are not really rendering a `<Router>`, React Router is throwing this error.

You can check more information here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/f97d0b7e1ff572aa6711fe29b54e6b8fdf9efddf/lessons/02-rendering-a-route#rendering-a-route

Answer (score 3):

This post is a kind of old, I came here a bit late, maybe the find below can help someone later on.

In case, just the test has failed due to the Link outside a Router component, please take a look at MemoryRouter to test the Link component.

Here is a link just for people to test props and stuff in unit tests:

- [https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/**tests**/Link-test.js](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/__tests__/Link-test.js)

```js
const node = document.createElement("div");
ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Link to="/" innerRef={refCallback}>link</Link>
  </MemoryRouter>,
  node
)
```